# Docx4j scale image to parent element

Tags: java, docx4j

I want to scale an image in docx4j to match the width of it's parent if it's too large to fit on the page. For example maybe it's inside a table cell which has a width or bigger than the page.

I'm currently playing with the `int width = box.getContainingBlock().getWidth();` and `int imagewidth = imagePart.getImageInfo().getSize().getWidthMpt();` but the values don't seem to be correct. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/81fecde856e80602a168cee8d3df70269668a9dc (in 3.3.0) addressed this use case, adding:

```
public Inline createImageInline(String filenameHint, String altText, 
            int id1, int id2, boolean link, int maxWidth) throws Exception
```

but you do need to know the width of the parent.

Example of usage https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/279b5bcc91ff65d4dc5b88f08b8f6e9815b12563

Comment: I have been playing with the maxWidth parameter of this method but the sizes are strange. I have ImageSize object in mpt or px. I then have the parentBox (InlineLayoutBox object) which has a width and the createImageInline method seems to take in a width in twips. Do you know which widths I should be using?

Comment: Please add the XML representing the parent object.  What created that: Word, docx4j, or something else?

Comment: in 6.0.1, maxWidth not working for me. createImageInline(String filenameHint, String altText, int id1, int id2, long cx, boolean link) is working perfect